# Where can I find or could you provide the definition of a category using dependent types?

Tags: category-theory, definition, computer-science, type-theory, programming

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type

I would prefer though Coq code.

Is this the only (quality) option:

https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/tree/master/theories/Categories 
?

But I don't understand HoTT, so would it be too difficult to use that HoTT library, or could I learn a little bit of HoTT and be okay?

One reason why that would be a bad idea is I would have to translate the Coq code into Python 3.x which has a dependent types feature, which I'm going to use for something.

Comment: Categories have been defined in the mathlib library for the Lean theorem prover here (https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/master/src/category_theory/category.lean) which is similar enough to Coq. A word of warning: people I know who have tried to do things with categories in dependently typed languages have encountered a lot of headaches trying to deal with universe levels -- I have no idea how your Python implementation is going to work, but it's something to be particularly conscious of. Basically, the universe levels confuse type inference.

Comment: @JackCrawford I don't mind paradoxes, as long as the user doesn't encounter them. :)  My app's sole purpose is on diagrams, so I'm not even sure how universes will come into play (?)

Comment: @JackCrawford thanks for the link.  On second  thought using Python's dependent type system would probably dead end very quickly, so I'll probably try to connect my app to Lean somehow.

Comment: If you're only looking to do rudimentary diagrams you perhaps don't need the full machinery of an automated theorem proving implementation like this, although I'm not sure what your use-case is like. The reason that universes come into it is because we'd like to be able to construct a category over any type, but then the morphisms between objects of that type have to sit at a higher universe level, etc. If you want to try to connect your app to Lean somehow, I believe a fork was made to Lean to enable a Python app to hook in somehow and it may have merged already https://github.com/khoek/klean

Comment: @JackCrawford Thanks for knowing so much about this!   You've saved me a lot of coding trouble.  So, is that klean the version that allows you to access it from Python?  Where can I see more information about accomplishing that?

Comment: Here's a use of hooking Lean into Python. This is a Python app to graph connections made in a rewrite search algorithm. I don't know what the current state of Klean is or whether it's relevant anymore, but it was developed to implement this: https://github.com/khoek/lean-rewrite-search

Comment: @JackCrawford I will need something that can reason about things, and have already tried coding a "logic framework in C++", but it gets difficult to do very quickly.   It's not only a diagram editor, it's supposed to guide you a bit in the proof of something or show what options are available at a certain step.

Comment: @JackCrawford sorry to bother you again, however, I'm not seeing anything on the "lean-rewrite-search" page in regards to Python.  I think you forgot to include the link to the python app.

Comment: I don't actually know how the implementation works so I can't help you out too much with it, but here's where it looks like the python stuff is located (https://github.com/khoek/lean-rewrite-search/tree/master/res/graph_tracer), and I think there's also a report (and maybe even a presentation?) in the form of some uncompiled .tex source files here that can probably help you (https://github.com/khoek/lean-rewrite-search/tree/master/article)

Comment: @JackCrawford I looked through the python code.  It does not connect to Lean or anything like that -_-  What I will end up doing probably is taking the Lean source code and compiling it to a DLL with whatever interface functions would be needed.  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97806/discussion-between-jack-crawford-and-shine-on-you-crazy-diamond).

Comment: The HoTT book has a whole chapter (chapter 9) devoted to the implementation of category theory, categories are defined as precategories satisfying a univalence like axiom, namely that categorical isomorphism is the same as type equality. If you're familiar with dependent type theory you only need to read 1.12, 2.1-2.4, 2.10 and 3.1 of the HoTT book to be able to follow the basics of the categories inplementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type-theoretic+definition+of+category) you can find a complete definition of category in a dependent type theory.

In summary it is an element of a $\Sigma$-type, or a record if you prefer, made of:

- a type $Obj$ whose elements are the objects
- a dependent type $\hom \colon Obj \times Obj \to \mathbf{Type}$
- a dependent function $\circ \colon \prod_{x,y,z \colon Obj} \hom(y,z) \times \hom(x,y) \to \hom(x,z)$ (in the uncurried version)
- a dependent function $1 \colon \prod_{x \colon Obj} \hom(x,x)$
- a proof $ass \colon \prod_{x,y,z,w} \prod_{f \colon \hom(x,y),g\colon \hom(y,z),h\colon \hom(z,w)} h \circ (g \circ f) = (h \circ g) \circ f$
- proofs for the left and right unit $left-unit \colon \prod_{x,y}\prod_{f\colon\hom(x,y)} f \circ 1_x = f$ and $right-unit \colon \prod_{x,y}\prod_{f\colon\hom(x,y)}  1_y \circ f= f$.

This can be easily implemented in any programming language/proof assistant with dependent types with an equality type (not necessarily HoTT).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  That is a really good explanation.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond glad to be of help.